# How to create jpeg image from base64 string in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, jpeg, clisp

I am working on a third-party application in Common Lisp. The server has a rest API that returns in response the profile photo of the account owner in base64 encoded format. I want to encode the image in jpeg using that base64 string and store it in local storage.

I use cl-jpeg package for creation of image. The package has an 'encode-image' function that takes the target file path, image array, height, width, and number of components.

When I call this function with a byte array created from a base64 string, the function creates a distorted image.

You can try the below example code:

```
(let* ((base64-string "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")
       (byte-array (base64:base64-string-to-usb8-array base64-string))
       (output-file-spec "/tmp/image.jpeg")
       (height 618)
       (width 1000)
       (ncomp 3))
  (cl-jpeg:encode-image output-file-spec byte-array ncomp height width))
```

I also tried creating image online from above base64 string an stored it in local storage. decode the image using cl-jpeg's decode-image function. It gives unsigned-byte 8 array, height ,width, number of components.

I used this data to encode the image using cl-jpeg's encode-image function and it works!

```
(multiple-value-bind (buff h w ncomp)
    (cl-jpeg:decode-image "<absolute jpeg image path>")
  (cl-jpeg:encode-image "/tmp/image.jpeg" buff ncomp h w))
```

Now i need to know how to convert base64 string to image?

Any suggetions will help

Thanks.

Comment: Clarification question: where do the 618x1000 dimensions come from? When I convert the example string to jpg (using the Linux terminal coreutils) then I get a perfect square 300x300 image (a grid of colored small squares). Is your goal to create a 618x1000 file with padding (white/black/transparent pixels) or clipping on the sides/top/bottom if necessary? Or do you want to extract the original dimensions from the input base64 string and use those? Or just scale the image as you do now?

Comment: Oops, my bad. Thanks for pointing out the incorrect dimensions mentioned. 300×300 dimensions are correct. The problem is to extract the original image from the input base64 string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base64 string already represents an encoded sequence of bytes of a JPEG file, you don't need to convert your base64 decoded bytes to JPEG, you just have to directly write the decoded bytes to a binary file like this :

```
(ql:quickload :cl-base64)

(defparameter *base64-string*
  "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")

(with-open-file (out "output.jpeg"
                     :direction :output
                     :if-exists :supersede
                     :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (write-sequence (cl-base64:base64-string-to-usb8-array *base64-string*) out))
```